# will I lose my data in other partitions when I install Ubuntu alongside Windows?

Tags: system-installation

I want to use both ubuntu and windows7 as dual booting, so please let me know because I had already lost data when I installed ubuntu as replace widows 7 with ubuntu, so I don't want to lose again.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it correctly NO data is deleted during installation of Ubuntu. There are just 2 steps in creating a dual boot:

1. Create unallocated space. Use a gParted live cd or partition magic to do this.
2. Use the unallocated space to install Ubuntu during the installation fase.

If done with these 2 steps the only partition that is getting changed is the unallocated one.

But as always: when using an operating system making a regular backup is the best method to keep your data safe. When changing partitions (or any alteration to your machine) it is wise to make another backup before committing these changes. And of course make sure the backup is indeed correctly created (so it can be restored if need be). Safety first.

Comment: can I do unallocated space in computer management by right clicking on that c-drive and selecting "shrink volume" option? or do I have to use that gParted live cd or partition magic what u suggested me? and also, present Iam using win7 premium, installed in drive-C and only 37GB free of 98GB is there any chances of losing program files or data to do partition in the c-drive? or do I have to install in separate drive? Thanking you in advance Mr.Rinzwind.